# Conditional Replace Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements, series

I have a DataFrame, and I want to replace the values in a particular column that exceed a value with zero. I had thought this was a way of achieving this:

```
df[df.my_channel > 20000].my_channel = 0
```

If I copy the channel into a new data frame it's simple:

```
df2 = df.my_channel 

df2[df2 > 20000] = 0
```

This does exactly what I want, but seems not to work with the channel as part of the original DataFrame.

Comment: Found what I think you were looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37841525/2662901).

Answer (score 276, accepted):

`.ix` indexer works okay for pandas version prior to 0.20.0, but since pandas 0.20.0, the `.ix` indexer is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated), so you should avoid using it. Instead, you can use `.loc` or `iloc` indexers. You can solve this problem by:

```
mask = df.my_channel > 20000
column_name = 'my_channel'
df.loc[mask, column_name] = 0
```

Or, in one line,

```
df.loc[df.my_channel > 20000, 'my_channel'] = 0
```

`mask` helps you to select the rows in which `df.my_channel > 20000` is `True`, while `df.loc[mask, column_name] = 0` sets the value 0 to the selected rows where `mask`holds in the column which name is `column_name`.

**Update:**
In this case, you should use `loc` because if you use `iloc`, you will get a `NotImplementedError` telling you that *iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available*.

Answer (score 102):

Try

```
df.loc[df.my_channel > 20000, 'my_channel'] = 0
```

**Note:**  Since v0.20.0, `ix` [has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) in favour of `loc` / `iloc`.

Comment: Thank you. I found my own solution too, which was: df.my_channel[df.my_channel >20000] = 0

Comment: @BMichell I think your solution might start giving you warnings in 0.13, didn't have a chance to try yet

Comment: yield error: /opt/anaconda3/envs/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Comment: @RutgerHofste thanks for mentioning that, yet another argument never use Python3

Answer (score 76):

[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function works as follows:

```
df['X'] = np.where(df['Y']>=50, 'yes', 'no')
```

In your case you would want:

```
import numpy as np
df['my_channel'] = np.where(df.my_channel > 20000, 0, df.my_channel)
```

Answer (score 35):

The reason your original dataframe does not update is because [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) may cause you to modify a copy rather than a view of your dataframe. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) give this advice:

> When setting values in a pandas object, care must be taken to avoid
>   what is called chained indexing.

You have a few alternatives:-

#### [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + Boolean indexing

`loc` may be used for setting values and supports Boolean masks:

```
df.loc[df['my_channel'] > 20000, 'my_channel'] = 0
```

#### [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) + Boolean indexing

You can assign to your series:

```
df['my_channel'] = df['my_channel'].mask(df['my_channel'] > 20000, 0)
```

Or you can update your series in place:

```
df['my_channel'].mask(df['my_channel'] > 20000, 0, inplace=True)
```

#### [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) + Boolean indexing

You *can* use NumPy by assigning your original series when your condition is *not* satisfied; however, the first two solutions are cleaner since they explicitly change only specified values.

```
df['my_channel'] = np.where(df['my_channel'] > 20000, 0, df['my_channel'])
```

Comment: What if you have multiple conditions to mask?

Comment: @Egidius I have used `np.select` if having multiple conditions, or otherwise the `&` and `|` operators in Pandas.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`df.my_channel = df.my_channel.where(df.my_channel <= 20000, other= 0)`

or

`df.my_channel = df.my_channel.mask(df.my_channel > 20000, other= 0)`

Answer (score 4):

I would use `lambda` function on a `Series` of a `DataFrame` like this:

```
f = lambda x: 0 if x>100 else 1
df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].map(f)
```

I do not assert that this is an efficient way, but it works fine.

Comment: This is inefficient and not recommended as it involves a Python-level loop in a row-wise operation.

Comment: Thank you, I guess we can use  `loc` here, like `df.loc[: , 'my_column'] = df['my_column'].map(f)` . I do not know if it is fast like the ones you added below.

Comment: Nope, still slow as you are still operating row-wise rather than column-wise.