# Replace values in Pandas Series Given Condition

Tags: python, pandas

This is a trivial question that I just have not been able to find a clear answer on:

I have a Series object:

```
random = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, 10)))
```

I want to replace all values greater than 1 with 0.  How do I do this?  I've tried
Random.replace() without success and I know you can do this easily in a DataFrame, but how do I do it in a Series object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not just try to set `s[s > 1] = 0`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ============================
np.random.seed(0)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
s

0    1.7641
1    0.4002
2    0.9787
3    2.2409
4    1.8676
5   -0.9773
6    0.9501
7   -0.1514
8   -0.1032
9    0.4106
dtype: float64


# ============================
s[s>1] = 0
s

0    0.0000
1    0.4002
2    0.9787
3    0.0000
4    0.0000
5   -0.9773
6    0.9501
7   -0.1514
8   -0.1032
9    0.4106
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You will get this warning: `__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` Try this instead `s = s.mask(s > 1, 0)`

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas