# Using a conditional statement to change the value of a variable

Tags: python

This may be a simple question, but I am having trouble finding a solution.  I have a variable named `T_wall` with a pandas Series containing numbers.  When that value is over `2,000,` I would like the `T_wall` to output `2,000`.

I have tried an if statement but I continue to get errors.  Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
T_wall = pd.Series([1999.0, 2000.0, 2001.0, 2002.0, 2003.0])

if T_wall > 2000.0:
    T_wall = 2000.0
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: what error you getting ? It should work

Comment: I am getting this error:ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: So `T_wall` is a pandas Series.

Comment: It looks like `T_wall` is not a int or float. Please post a full example that can be copied into a python interpreter and reproduces the error. I googled the error message and the first hit points to stackoverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o]

Comment: The error message you quote [in the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587124/using-a-conditional-statement-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable#comment115960418_65587124) tells you _exactly_ what the problem is, and _exactly_ how to fix it. Be sure you include the message in your question itself, going forward; also, a few words about how you understand that message and how you tried to apply its advice would help folks understand where you're coming from and how to better tailor answers to that perspective.

Comment: Please post a working example. You say you have a variable with an assigned value... actually assign that variable a value in the question. Your error message (which should be in the question itself) hints that this is a pandas series. Is that the type you expect? What do you want the output to be? A series with values > 2000.0 set to 2000? All values in the series set to 2000? T_wall replaced with a single float if any values are > 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T_wall is a pandas series, so instead you can loop through the series and then do your if statement:

```
for i in range(0, len(T_wall)):
    if T_wall[i] > 2000.0:
        T_wall[i] = 2000.0
```

Comment: Consider an apply function :)

Comment: I would strongly advice against using `for` loop in pandas. `apply` approach will be much faster

Comment: Or using `mask`? `T_wall.mask(T_wall > 2000, 2000)`

Comment: That worked thank you.  My apologies as I am new to python and how panda series work.

Answer (score 1):

Taking everything from the comments.
Avoid using `for` in pandas as much as possible. Here you can go with masking:

```py
T_wall[T_wall > 2000] = 2000
```

`apply` would also work

```py
T_wall.apply(lambda x: 2000 if x > 2000 else x)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `apply` examples is correct? Probably should be: `T_wall.apply(lambda x: 2000 if x > 2000 else x)`

Comment: @de1 you're right, it wasn't good. Updated

Answer (score 0):

To complete the question with an example.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ser = pd.Series([1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
>>> ser
0    1999
1    2000
2    2001
3    2002
4    2003
dtype: int64
```

### Meaning of `ser > 2000`

```
>>> ser > 2000
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

As you can see `ser > 2000` returns a series itself, with `True` or `False` values, depending on whether the condition matched.

There are several ways to then use that condition.

### The `mask` function

[mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) can accept the condition and returns a new Series that "replaces" the values with the provided value (the original series won't change unless you set `inplace`). (See also [Mask User Guide section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#mask))

```
>>> ser.mask(ser > 2000, 2000)
0    1999
1    2000
2    2000
3    2000
4    2000
dtype: int64
```

That is somewhat equivalent to:

```
>>> [(2000 if x > 2000 else x) for x in ser]
[1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000]
```

### The `where` function

[where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) is the inverse of mask, therefore you'd want to invert the condition to achieve the same effect. Here the second argument is `other`, providing the replacement value where the condition is `False`. (See also [Where User Guide section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking))

```
>>> ser.where(ser <= 2000, 2000)
0    1999
1    2000
2    2000
3    2000
4    2000
dtype: int64
```

That is somewhat equivalent to:

```
>>> [(x if x <= 2000 else 2000) for x in ser]
[1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000]
```

### assignment via boolean indexing

You can also change the series directly via [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) as indicated in other answers (adding for completeness):

```
>>> ser
0    1999
1    2000
2    2001
3    2002
4    2003
dtype: int64
>>> ser[ser > 2000] = 2000
>>> ser
0    1999
1    2000
2    2000
3    2000
4    2000
dtype: int64
```

(That would then be equivalent to `ser.mask(ser > 2000, 2000, inplace=True)`)

### The `apply` function

You could also use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) (also with an optional `inplace` parameter):

```
>>> ser = pd.Series([1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003])
>>> ser.apply(lambda x: 2000 if x > 2000 else x)
0    1999
1    2000
2    2000
3    2000
4    2000
dtype: int64
```

That allows you to use a regular Python function or expression. But it won't be as efficient for large series as the other examples, as it will call the Python expression for each value rather than doing everything within Pandas (vectorized).

### Similar questions

- [Replace values in Pandas Series Given Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545183/replace-values-in-pandas-series-given-condition)
- [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

The most pandas-way answer would be:

```
T_wall[T_wall > 2000.0] = 2000.0
```

Example:

```
data = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
data[data > 2] = 5
```

`data`:

```
0    1
1    2
2    5
3    5
4    5
```

Pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking