# if else function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I'm trying to apply an if condition over a dataframe, but I'm missing something (error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().)

```
raw_data = {'age1': [23,45,21],'age2': [10,20,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2'])

def my_fun (var1,var2,var3):
if (df[var1]-df[var2])>0 :
    df[var3]=df[var1]-df[var2]
else:
    df[var3]=0
print(df[var3])

my_fun('age1','age2','diff')
```

Comment: The error means, that in your selected columns are some values, which are evaluated as True and also some, which are evaluated as False. You may need to run my_fun per row.

Comment: I don't know this approach per row, could you give me any hint please?

Comment: See the answer by @jezrael, it's much better solution

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def my_fun (var1,var2,var3):
    df[var3]= np.where((df[var1]-df[var2])>0, df[var1]-df[var2], 0)
    return df

df1 = my_fun('age1','age2','diff')
print (df1)
   age1  age2  diff
0    23    10    13
1    45    20    25
2    21    50     0
```

Error is better explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922103/2901002).

Slowier solution with `apply`, where need `axis=1` for data processing by rows:

```
def my_fun(x, var1, var2, var3):
    print (x)
    if (x[var1]-x[var2])>0 :
        x[var3]=x[var1]-x[var2]
    else:
        x[var3]=0
    return x    

print (df.apply(lambda x: my_fun(x, 'age1', 'age2','diff'), axis=1))
   age1  age2  diff
0    23    10    13
1    45    20    25
2    21    50     0
```

Also is possible use `loc`, but sometimes data can be overwritten:

```
def my_fun(x, var1, var2, var3):
    print (x)
    mask = (x[var1]-x[var2])>0
    x.loc[mask, var3] = x[var1]-x[var2]
    x.loc[~mask, var3] = 0

    return x    

print (my_fun(df, 'age1', 'age2','diff'))
   age1  age2  diff
0    23    10  13.0
1    45    20  25.0
2    21    50   0.0
```

Comment: the point is that in real life the conditions are more tricky and it seems that nesting with the np.where could be a little tricky to read. is there any change to do it with a more tradition if-elif-else statement?

Comment: I add solution with `apply`. You are right, if meany complicated conditions with many elif, apply is better.

Comment: thanks, since you asked more details I opened another topic, just to avoid confusion in this 3d. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393672/looping-into-dates-and-apply-function-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 14):

You can use `pandas.Series.where`

```
df.assign(age3=(df.age1 - df.age2).where(df.age1 > df.age2, 0))

   age1  age2  age3
0    23    10    13
1    45    20    25
2    21    50     0
```

---

You can wrap this in a function

```
def my_fun(v1, v2):
    return v1.sub(v2).where(v1 > v2, 0)

df.assign(age3=my_fun(df.age1, df.age2))

   age1  age2  age3
0    23    10    13
1    45    20    25
2    21    50     0
```

Answer (score 14):

There is another way without `np.where` or `pd.Series.where`. Am not saying it is better, but after trying to adapt this solution to a challenging problem today, was finding the syntax for `where` no so intuitive. In the end, not sure whether it would have possible with where, but found the following method lets you have a look at the subset before you modify it and it for me led more quickly to a solution. Works for the OP here of course as well.

You deliberately set a value on a slice of a dataframe as Pandas so often warns you not to.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37841750/4288043) answer shows you the correct method to do that.

The following gives you a slice:

```
df.loc[df['age1'] - df['age2'] > 0]
```

..which looks like:

```
   age1  age2
0    23    10
1    45    20
```

Add an extra column to the original dataframe for the values you want to remain after modifying the slice:

```
df['diff'] = 0
```

Now modify the slice:

```
df.loc[df['age1'] - df['age2'] > 0, 'diff'] = df['age1'] - df['age2']
```

..and the result:

```
   age1  age2  diff
0    23    10    13
1    45    20    25
2    21    50     0
```