# looping into dates and apply function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, pandas, for-loop, apply

I'm trying to detect the first dates when an event occur: here in my dataframe for the product A (see pivot table) I have 20 items stored for the first time on 2017-04-03.

so I want to create a new variable calle new_var_2017-04-03 that store the increment. On the other hand on the next day  2017-04-04 I don't mind if the item is now 50 instead of 20, I only want to store only the 1st event

It gives me several errors, I would like to know at least if the entire logic behind it makes sense, it's "pythonic", or if I'm completeley on the wrong way

```
raw_data = {'name': ['B','A','A','B'],'date' : pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2017-03-30','2017-03-31','2017-04-03','2017-04-04'])),
    'age': [10,20,50,30]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['date','name','age'])


table=pd.pivot_table(df1,index=['name'],columns=['date'],values=['age'],aggfunc='sum')
table
```

I'm passing the dates to a list

```
dates=df1['date'].values.tolist()
```

I want to do a backward loop into my list "dates" and create a variable if an event occurs.
pseudo code: with i-1 I mean the item before i in the list

```
def my_fun(x,list):
    for i in reversed(list):
        if (x[i]-x[i-1])>0 :
            x[new_var+i]=x[i]-x[i-1]
    else:
        x[new_var+i]=0
return x  

print (df.apply(lambda x: my_fun(x,dates), axis=1))
```

desidered output:

```
raw_data2 = {'new_var': ['new_var_2017-03-30','new_var_2017-03-31','new_var_2017-04-03','new_var_2017-04-04'],'result_a': [np.nan,20,np.nan,np.nan],'result_b': [10,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
df2= pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns = ['new_var','result_a','result_b'])

df2.T
```

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: desidered results added, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df1['age'] = df1.groupby('name')['age'].transform(lambda x: (x==x.min())*x)
df1.pivot_table(index='name', columns='date', values='age').replace(0,np.nan)


date  2017-03-30  2017-03-31  2017-04-03  2017-04-04
name                                                
A            NaN        20.0         NaN         NaN
B           10.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: it works thanks, but I don't understand the logic behind this: (x==x.min())*x). you calculate the min of x and apply it to the df with a lambda function and...what?

Comment: for every value of 'x' passed check to see if it is the minimum.  If it is then, (x==x.min()) evaluates to True.  which get casts as 1.0*x. Else, it evaluates as False which gets casts as 0.0.  So, 1 * min value and 0 * other values.  The groupby pass age into the lambda function in groups, so it takes finds the min of that group and multiple it by one and  the other values multiply by 0.

Comment: or  df1['age'] = df1.groupby('name')['age'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x==x.min(),x,np.nan))

Comment: or df1['age'] = df1.groupby('name')['age'].transform(lambda x: x.where(x == x.min()))