# Applying the IF function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iif-function

WHat better syntax can I use for the operation below?
Column A has variables containing 2 different SI units with different conversion methods: in KB as well MB.
So, I want to do the following actions on the column which is in a pandas dataframe:
data = pd.dataframe({"sizes":[12mb, 7kb, 17kb, 11mn], "song-type":["karaoke", "rock", "jazz", "rap"]}, index = [1,2,3,4])

I want to extract the numerics from size and multiply each numeric component of the variables having 'mb' with 1000. Then have the results in int or float format

```
if 'M' in x:
    extract the numerics in x
    convert to float
    and assign x to (x * by 1000)
elif 'K' in x:
    extract the numerics in x and convert to float
    and assign it to x
else:
    extract the numerics in x and convert to float
    and assign it to x
```

Comment: provide minimal reproducible data and code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if else function in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391591/if-else-function-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Looks like a units conversion so  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684548/convert-the-string-2-90k-to-2900-or-5-2m-to-5200000-in-pandas-dataframe might be helpful.