# Why does this code throw a SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

so I'm trying to create a new column that indicates whether or not the specified condition is True. I want the column to simply state "1" or "0".

Here's my code:

```
data_sub = data_orig.loc[~pd.isnull(data_orig['Last_Audit_Date']), :]
data_sub.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_sub['PackageLengthFlag'] = (abs(data_sub.loc['AUDIT_Primary_Length'] - data_sub.loc[:, 'PKG_SUB_Length']) > threshold)
```

I am thinking that True = 1 and False = 0 by default, if I convert it into integers, right? (thought I read somewhere saying this...)

And here's the warning that I keep getting:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of 
a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I read into:

[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

[Correct way to set value on a slice in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841525/correct-way-to-set-value-on-a-slice-in-pandas)

[Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)

But I don't think they do what I am looking for. 
Anyone has any advice? I know this question may sound painfully stupid, but still appreciate any help!

**Edit**
I've added the 2 lines of code where I created the data_sub. Hope that helps!

Comment: The source of this error isn't here, but probably in the code preceeding this. You probably tried to extract some sub-slice of your dataframe without calling `.copy` which generates this error.

Comment: You are getting that warning most likely because `data_sub` is a copy of a slice

Comment: Its hard to guess without sample df but this should work. data_sub['PackageLengthFlag'] = (np.abs(data_sub['AUDIT_Primary_Length'] - data_sub['PKG_SUB_Length']) > threshold).astype(int)

Comment: I've added the 2 lines of code where I created the data_sub. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the code above this, when you try extracting some dataframe subslice without making a complete copy, so the reference you have is actually a reference to part of another larger dataframe.

Without much context on what you're trying to do, just make a copy beforehand:

```
data_sub = data_sub.copy()
data_sub['PackageLengthFlag'] = (
    data_sub['AUDIT_Primary_Length']
        .sub(data_sub['PKG_SUB_Length'])
        .abs()
        .gt(threshold)
        .astype(int)
```

Call `df.abs` to perform the `abs` function on the entire result. `abs` is a vanilla python method that cannot handle `pd.Series` objects.

One final `astype` call converts the result to integral values.

---

Here's an example of what you're doing:

```
df

  A_Key B_ID C_Key  D_NA
0   123   22   343    23
1   121   23  45.4    52

x = df.iloc[[0], :]
x

  A_Key B_ID C_Key  D_NA
0   123   22   343    23

x.iloc[:, 0] += 2
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:517: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

You see the error generated. But in most cases, the original should still be modified without affecting the original. Now, copy first:

```
x = x.copy()
x.iloc[:, 0] += 2  # no warning
```

And you see the error suppressed. Interestingly, the same behaviour is not seen when performing similar operations on vertical subslices. I believe pandas smartly handles this by returning a full independent copy.

Comment: I've added the 2 lines of code where I created the data_sub. I reset the index so i thought it wouldnt have issue anymore?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions Operations on a loc slice are supposed to reflect on the original. And so you get the warning. My answer holds.

Comment: so you are saying, after i slice the data, i need to create another copy?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions Yes, if you're performing a horizontal slice. See edit. I don't know how much more to convince you!

Comment: Thank you so much! No no, I wasnt doubting you, I was simply not clear on what to do. But now I get it. Thanks very much!