# pandas chained_assignment warning exception handling

Tags: python, pandas, exception

If you worked in python with pandas you already know the chained_assignment warning when working on slices of dataframes (as e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841525/correct-way-to-set-value-on-a-slice-in-pandas)).

I found the option `pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment` which can be set to

- `None`, ignoring the warning
- `"warn"`, printing a warning message
- `"raise"`, raising an exception

compare with [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html)

I included a minimal example, triggering this warning within a `try..except..else` block for exception handling. I expect an exception to be triggered only with the setting `pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment = "raise"`, as shown in Example 3 below.

In this minimal example, the behaviour is as expected, so that Example 2, with 
`pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment = "warn"` only causes a warning message to be printed, but no exception is raised.

However in a larger framework, I see an exception being raised even though the parameter is set to `pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment = "warn"`, checked with a print before like in the minimal example (see Example 4)

**Is there any other pandas parameter influencing the behavior of this warning message concerning exception raising?**

---

Here is a minimal example of code, setting/printing the `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment` parameter and showing the behaviour in a `try..catch..except` block.

```
import pandas as pd

# set the chained_assignment option
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = "raise" # raises exception in case of warning
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = "warn"  # prints warning in case of warning, no exception is raised
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None    # no warning message and no exception is raised

print "pd.options.mode.chained_assignment :", pd.options.mode.chained_assignment

# create a default pandas dataframe with two columns A,B
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [0, 1, 2], "B" : [3, 4, 5]})

print df

# exctract a slice of the given pandas dataframe
df2 = df[df["A"] > 0]

# exception handling
try :
    # try to modify the slice, triggering the pandas warning
    df2["C"] = 2
except :
    print "EXCEPTION RAISED"
else :
    print "NO EXCEPTION"

print df2
```

---

Example 1
Setting `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` results in the following output (no warning, no exception)

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment : None
   A  B
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5
NO EXCEPTION
   A  B  C
1  1  4  2
2  2  5  2
```

---

Example 2
Setting `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = "warn"` results in the following output (a warning is printed, but no exception)

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment : warn
   A  B
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5
NO EXCEPTION
C:\Users\my.name\my\directory\test.py:14:SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df2["C"] = 2
   A  B  C
1  1  4  2
2  2  5  2
```

---

Example 3
Setting `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = "raise"` results in the following output (an exception is raised)

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment : raise
A  B
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5
EXCEPTION RAISED
   A  B  C
1  1  4  2
2  2  5  2
```

---

Example 4
This is what I see in a larger framework with exactly the same test code. I do not set the chained `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment` parameter explictly, but I see it's set to `"warn"`, even though an exception is raised

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment warn
   A  B
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5
EXCEPTION RAISED
   A  B  C
1  1  4  2
2  2  5  2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a long search, the "bad guy" was found.
Another developer included the following lines in his module

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
```

This turns warnings into exceptions. For more details see [warnings package documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html)

Hence my warnings were treated as exceptions, although the pandas option was set to "warn"