# Validate that Values in DataFrame Found in List

Tags: python, list, pandas, validation, dataframe

What's the best way to validate that the values in a column in a data frame match those in a given list (and, if not, are set to a value accordingly)?

I'm trying to replace invalid values for a field ("B") with the value "(not set)".

Here's what I've tried. The goal is to replace 'f' in 'B' with "(not set)". The trouble is validating against a list of values rather than a single boolean expression.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']})
valid_values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
validated_data = df.'B' not in [valid_values]
column_name = 'B'
df.loc[validated_data, column_name] = "(not set)"
```

The above taken from here:
[Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas/21608417)

I've also tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']})
valid_values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for x in df.B:
    if x not in valid_values:
        df.B = "(not set)"
...
```

However, for both I get the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous." I tried the recommendations at the following post to no avail.

[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Other recommendations greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Thank you. Error's answer below does this, but I will also edit the above for future passers by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `isin` method of `Series` and `DataFrame` objects.

Consider this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3,4,5,6], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f','a','b','c']})
```

Resulting in this DataFrame:

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   f
3   4   a
4   5   b
5   6   c
```

Let's say we want to remove invalid values in column B and those invallid values are a en b.

When we use the `isin` method we can run this code:

```
mask = df['B'].isin(['a','b'])
df.loc[mask,'B'] = 'not set'
```

Resulting in this DataFrame:

```
    A   B
0   1   not set
1   2   not set
2   3   f
3   4   not set
4   5   not set
5   6   c
```

The `isin` method checks if the values in a Series or DataFrame object are in the given iterable. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for more information.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I adjusted `mask = df['B'].isin(['a','b'])` to be `mask = ~df['B'].isin(['a','b'])` so that it is checking if a value is NOT in the given list.