# If value in 'amount' is < 0 then move to new array

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried several different ways to solve this problem but none of them helped me out.

I'm importing csv data out of Finanzblick, and I have an array called `amount`. If the values within this array' (e.g. `19.34`) are positive (greater than zero) then it should be transferred to the array `inflow`. If the value is negative (e.g. `-19.34`) it should be transferred to 'outflow'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.core.tools.numeric import to_numeric
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/PD/Desktop/Finanzblick Dokumente/2017_11/2017_11-
DB.csv", sep=';',usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), encoding='utf-8', decimal=',')
df.columns = ['Date', 'Payee', 'Verwendungszweck', 'Buchungstext', 'Betrag']

df['Memo'] = df[['Buchungstext', 'Verwendungszweck']].apply(lambda x: ' -- '.join(x), axis=1)

Betrag = df.Betrag.astype(int)
df['Inflow']  = np.where(df.Betrag > 0, df.Betrag, "")
df['Outflow'] = np.where(df.Betrag < 0, df.Betrag*(-1), "")

df.to_csv('C:/Users/PD/source/repos/Finanzblick YNAB/Finanzblick YNAB/2017_11-DB-import.csv',sep=';', index = False, columns=['Date', 'Payee', 'Memo', 'Inflow', 'Outflow'], decimal='.')
```

Greetings Phil

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: But maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21608228/2901002)

Comment: Using mask i get the result: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
Using int(df.amount) i got: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: Change `int(df.amount)` to `df.amount.astype(int)`

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-62,62'            mask = df.amount.astype(int) < 0
column_name = 'outflow'
df.loc[mask, outflow] = 0

Comment: I think need `decimal` in `read_csv` like `df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/PD/Desktop/Finanzblick Dokumente/2017_11/2017_11-
DB.csv", sep=';',usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), encoding='utf-8', decimal=',')` - it convert `,` to `.` and numbers to numeric floats.

Comment: I think this works but next error is: "NameError: name 'outflow' is not defined" in code: "df.loc[mask, outflow] = 0"

Comment: Check solution bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your positive and negative numbers are in an array the following will separate them by sign:

```
inflows  = np.where(amount > 0, amount, 0.)
outflows = np.where(amount < 0, amount, 0.)
```

If they are in a DataFrame, use this:

```
df['inflows']  = np.where(df.amount > 0, df.amount, 0.)
df['outflows'] = np.where(df.amount < 0, df.amount, 0.)
```

Comment: If 'Betrag' is a DataFrame column you have to use the second variation.

Comment: Hi @jezrael: This works perfect. I got it. Problem was only the notation. Thx a lot!!!!!