# Pandas Setting Conditional Values based on Log Result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a condition like this:

```
!(log(RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines) > 3)
```

I want to assign all values in the Dataseries based on this condition.

Something like:

```
df.loc[np.log(df.RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines) > 3, 'WeirdRevolvingUtilization'] = 0
```

I can't seem to find anything using custom functions like a Log or anything, any ideas?

Comment: It looks like dupe [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21608228/2901002)

Comment: Both Wen's and your own answers are good. But if either are too slow for you, you should try and vectorise your calcs in underlying numpy. Just use pandas to build results table.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems it was simple:

```
df.loc[np.log(df.RevolvingUtilizationOfUnsecuredLines) > 3, 'WeirdRevolvingUtilization'] = 0
```

I still don't know if this is the best solution.