# How to replace one col values with another col values in conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
df.head(10)
7   RT (min)    Area (Ab*s) Quality patch   similarity
8   10.167      23278313    64      NaN     NaN
9   10.167      23278313    47      NaN     NaN
10  10.167      23278313    38      NaN     NaN
28  10.333      3407159     49      10.167  0.983935
29  10.333      3407159     22      10.167  0.983935
30  10.333      3407159     16      10.167  0.983935
48  10.390      3299202     38      10.333  0.994514
49  10.390      3299202     35      10.333  0.994514
50  10.390      3299202     32      10.333  0.994514
68  10.516      2015786     50      10.390  0.988018
```

and I want when `df['similarity']>0.99`,and then  `df['RT (min)'] = df['patch']`. 
for example, df should like this:

```
7   RT (min)    Area (Ab*s) Quality patch   similarity
8   10.167      23278313    64      NaN     NaN
9   10.167      23278313    47      NaN     NaN
10  10.167      23278313    38      NaN     NaN
28  10.333      3407159     49      10.167  0.983935
29  10.333      3407159     22      10.167  0.983935
30  10.333      3407159     16      10.167  0.983935
48  10.333      3299202     38      10.333  0.994514
49  10.333      3299202     35      10.333  0.994514
50  10.333      3299202     32      10.333  0.994514
68  10.516      2015786     50      10.390  0.988018
```

48,49,50 rows in RT (min) is replace with  48,49,50 rows in patch

I have try

```
p = df[df['similarity']>0.99].index.tolist()
df['RT (min)'][p] =df['patch'][p]
```

while I get the error

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I don't know how to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
mask = df['similarity'] > 0.99
df.loc[mask, 'RT'] = df['patch']
```

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"RT":[10.1,10.2,10.4],"patch":[float("NaN"),10.3,10.3],"similarity":[float("NaN"),0.9,0.998]})
```

Producing:

```
    RT  patch   similarity
0   10.1    NaN NaN
1   10.2    10.3    0.900
2   10.4    10.3    0.998
```

Create a mask and use to assign values from `patch`

```
mask = df['similarity'] > 0.99
df.loc[mask, 'RT'] = df['patch']
```

Result:

```
RT  patch   similarity
0   10.1    NaN NaN
1   10.2    10.3    0.900
2   10.3    10.3    0.998
```

Comment: You are perfectly solved my problem, thank you for you detail answer

Comment: @X.tang great - please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)

You can assign as follows:

```
df['RT'] = df['RT'].mask(df['similarity'] > 0.99, df['patch'])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21608228 ?