# Change column (categorical) value based on another column (float)

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, replace

I try to execute this code to replace all df_dash['aoh'] <=262 to standby

```
if df_dash['aoh'] <= 262:
   df_dash['category'] = 'standby'
```

However I get this error, and I cannot seem to find a way to get the right results.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/MERS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I have read about this error in other threads, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this specific case.

I tried using this as well

```
df_dash['category'] = np.where(df_dash['aoh'] <= 262, 'standby', df['category'])
```

But, I get

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (458,) () (4173,)
```

Hoping someone could help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 df_dash['category'][df_dash['aoh'] <= 262] = 'standby'
```

Comment: it works perfectly, but don't you think it can be just as good to use loc? @YongkangZhao

Comment: loc is better when the df slice is being pass around functions to make sure the data is being passed as reference in case it needs to be modified inplace

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_dash.loc[df_dash['aoh'] <= 262,'category'] = 'standby'
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth nothing - your `np.where` solution should have worked, but I think you used `df['category']` in the second part of the function call, not `df_dash['category']`.

Can't see the rest of the code but assume the dataframes are different sizes.