# Replace value in Pandas DataFrame column, based on a condition (contains a string)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working with a pandas dataset (US startups) and am trying to aggregate sectors by keywords. In other words, I need to loop through a column and if a value contains a given string, replace the whole value with a new string.

If already tried some simple "if" statement loops, but can't seem to get the syntax right. I've also tried some .loc, but all I can seem to do is replace all values of the column with one string.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some sample test data and expected ouputs to this question?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is store the mappings of sectors to sector categories as a dictionary, and then apply a function that calls that mapping.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(["chunky spam", "watery spam", "hard-boiled", "scrambled"])

def mapping(sector):
    mapping_dict = {"chunky spam": "spam", 
                    "watery spam": "spam", 
                    "hard-boiled": "eggs", 
                    "scrambled": "eggs"}

    return mapping_dict[sector]

data[0].apply(mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using `pd.DataFrame.where()`:

```py
df.where(df.column_name != "str", "replace")
```

Based on the formulation of the `df.where()` method, it will replace all of the values that DO NOT match the condition. This is why we use the negated `!=` when looking for `"str"` in some column. All instance which are equal to `"str"` will be replaced with the string `"replace"`