# Pandas replace row value in df if value has more than two spaces

Tags: python, pandas

I have to clean a database

```
Id  FirstName LastName
12  Jannie    Pretorious
15  Elsa      Van Niekerk
14  Koos      SC$ 4 MMV Extraction SHift B
```

I want to remove the values that aren't LastNames, in this example id 14 : Koos SC$ 4 ...

I can identify a faulty lastname if there is more than two spaces within the cell value.

I want to iterate through the df and replace all values, with more than two spaces, with ''.

I have looked at this question [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas), but it didn't help me.

Expected output:

```
Id  FirstName LastName
12  Jannie    Pretorious
15  Elsa      Van Niekerk
14  Koos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['LastName'] = df['LastName'].mask(df['LastName'].str.count(' ') > 2, '')
print (df)
   Id FirstName     LastName
0  12    Jannie   Pretorious
1  15      Elsa  Van Niekerk
2  14      Koos
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['LastName'].str.count(' '))
0    0
1    1
2    5
Name: LastName, dtype: int64
```

Alternative:

```
df['LastName'] = df['LastName'].mask(df['LastName'].str.split().str.len().sub(1) > 2, '')
```