# Replace value in one column, if another column satisfies a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I can't figure out how to write this
If df['col1']=='A' then df['col2'].replace('X','Y', inplace = True)

I write something like df[df['col1'] == 'A']['col2'].replace('X','Y', inplace = True) but it is giving me an error and I can't work out a solution to it.

I am trying to get a value in a column replaced, if a condition is met in another column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas) Specifically, look at the answer given by @seeiespi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48795837/12131013

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `inplace=True`. You are trying that way to modify the "source" dataframe, but that dataframe is just a partial view (a slice) of another dataframe, so it is "read-only".

It is a little bit like
`df[(df.col1=='A') & (df.col2=='X')]['col2'] = 'Y'`

That would fail for the same reason: can't modify `['col2']` of dataframe `df[(df.col1=='A') & (df.col2=='X')]`, since that dataframe is a slice of `df`.

What you can do is

```py
df.loc[(df.col1=='A') & (df.col2=='X'), 'col2'] = 'Y'
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much. I've been trying to solve it for ages.

Comment: If this solves your problem, then you should accept the answer.